How to use Xpath Plugin in Cypress V13.14.2 after depreciation of plugin
I did all these steps but still not working
Installing = npm install -D cypress-xpath
xpath reference to your support/command.js = 
code under support/e2e.js file = require('cypress-xpath');
Still getting error for xpath
enter image description here
I tried all these steps for adding the plugin but still getting the same error
